# Display user field into html.tpl.php

Tags: entities, theming, users

In my `user-profile.tpl.php` file In print fields like this :

```
<?php 


    global $user;
    $user_id = arg(1);

    $user_item = user_load_by_name($user->name);


    if($user->uid == $user_id) {
        echo 'I'm connected';
        print render ($user_profile['field_mon_statut']);
    }

 ?>
```

I wrote this exact same code in html.tpl.php but it does not appear..

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

U are setting $user variable inside if condition, while in if u have condition that $user->uid, so it will compute as false, and it will not go inside if condition.

You will have to write:

```
global $user;
if($user->uid) {
// Your code
```

// Edited

```
global $user;
$user_id = arg(1);

// $user_item = user_load($user->uid);

if($user->uid == $user_id) {
    echo 'I m connected';
    print render ($user_profile['field_mon_statut']);
}
```

Comment: I did this but still not work

Comment: Why are u using double if condition.. ?, and what is user_profile, it is not set.I think it is not complete code, can u provide me complete code of the file.

Comment: I edited my post, you can check it

Comment: ($user->uid != 0) use this condition in your code

Comment: Please try above edited answer..

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the line where you use `echo`

```
<?php 
    global $user;
    $user_id = arg(1);

    $user_item = user_load_by_name($user->name);

    if($user->uid == $user_id) {
        echo "I'm connected";
        print render ($user_profile['field_mon_statut']);
    }

 ?>
```

Try to use the code above and check.